# How to Change Style of Span When Hovering Input

Tags: css

I would like to change the style of a `<span />` which is not a child element of the input. I tried to find the `<span />` with `+` and `>`, but I could never change it.

Is it possible to change style of it with pure css/scss?

```css
#input:hover,
#input:focus-within {
  span { color: red; }
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="input" value='' />
<div>
  <span>My colour should change when hovering the input.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: NB: the target duplicates each serve as part of the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) and [child combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) like:

```css
#input:hover+div>span,
#input:focus-within+div>span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="input" value='' />
<div>
  <span>My colour should change when hovering the input.</span>
</div>
```

Note that the child (`>`) combinator isn't required but it makes sure you only select the span that's a child and not all span descendants should there be others. You could also use the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (`~`) instead of the adjacent one, but again the specificity seems more helpful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code:

```css
input[type="search"]#input:hover ~ div span {
   color: red; 
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="input" value='' />
<div>
  <span>My colour should change when hovering the input.</span>
</div>
```